# Exercise asking what a transistor circuit does

Tags: transistors, mosfet, circuit-analysis, cmos

[image]

This exercise from the book *Introduction to Computing Systems from Bits and Gates to C/C++ & Beyond* by Yale N. Patt and Sanjay J. Pattel asks what this transistor circuit does. I don't understand how I'm supposed to answer this question. Should I give the truth table of the circuit? If so, should I consider two cases when the upper wire is on or off, too?

Edit: here's the truth table I came up with

| A | OUT |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | disconnected from both ground and power supply |
| 1 | connected to both ground and power supply |

Comment: I’d assume upper wire is Vcc.

Comment: I don't think so because they didn't tell that, also in the book they don't represent Vcc this way with dots that show intersection and they only use a short line not a big one like here, so I think this is a normal wire and not Vcc

Comment: With unknown voltage on that line, you can't tell if you can turn on the P-FETs.

Comment: but you can consider 2 cases, when it's on and when it's off

Comment: Perhaps the first thing is to think if it even makes sense or not. You can figure out by starting to writie a truth table, and maybe it is impossible to write a truth table for this circuit if only states on and off are considered.

Comment: I was wrong, I just realized that if the upper wire is off the OUT wire will always be off no matter how A is

Comment: Please go ahead and make the truth table.

Comment: @winny I added the truth table to my question

Comment: Strange that the upper wire has no label. A **power supply?** A **bus?** In either case, circuit function is somewhat odd. If you draw a truth table, consider not only **0, 1** for output state, but also **Hi-Z** (high impedance, or tri-state).

Comment: @glen_geek I'm not really good with electricity, so I don't exactly know what "impedance" and "tri-state" mean. But I do notice that this circuit is not a normal one.

Comment: impedance ~= resistance. You've stumbled upon an interesting circuit that is likely in use on almost all digital electronics. Basically Hi-Z means disconnect this section of the circuit from the wire/bus.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Should I give the truth table of the circuit?

Yes.

> should I consider two cases when the upper wire is on or off, too?

No, because the upper wire is the supply, and without it the circuit will not do anything useful. The outputs won't be driving any valid logic states, and also the V-I curve for the outputs will be determined by the details of the semiconductor process and layout used. So the outputs won't have any reasonable interpretation in terms of a digital logic system.

> I’d assume upper wire is Vcc

> I don't think so because they didn't tell that

Indeed they didn't, because it's a convention that people with experience in the field are used to. They forgot to share it with the readers, who are **not** experienced in the field. An experienced EE would not be reading such a book. So they somewhat forgot their audience...

> also in the book they don't represent Vcc this way with dots that show intersection

The dots show *connection* and the horizontal line on top of the circuit is the VCC rail. That's how such circuits are conventionally drawn. Except, again, the authors forgot to tell you that.

> and they only use a short line not a big one like here, so I think this is a normal wire and not Vcc

The "short line" is just one of the many conventions when drawing implied connections to supply rails. The authors and editors of an introductory book on this subject should be *very careful about maintaining consistency and explaining their use of symbols*.

Academic publishers, unfortunately, often forget that technical editors - if they have them to start with - need to have domain expertise *and* understand the educational segment they work for. I have my doubts that this was the case here.

There's a saying in Polish "Zapomniał wół jak cielęciem był." - meaining "The bull has since forgotten how it was to be a calf." Beginner students in all topics are easily driven astray by "minor" editorial omissions, since they don't have the experience to know what's important, what isn't, and what is just convention. It's entirely normal, and not your "fault" in any way. It's on the editorial staff at the publisher to understand this and do a good job.

> here's the truth table I came up with

It is a good truth table! To make it less verbose, you could use symbols for those two states:

| A | OUT |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | Z |
| 1 | X |

States:

- **0** logic zero
- **1** logic one
- **Z** high impedance
- **X** not a valid logic state - it is approximately 1/2 supply voltage, so neither a valid 1 nor a 0.

This legend describing the symbols should be written under the truth table, since at least "X" is not a widely used symbol, and "Z" is often written "hi-Z". It's best to be explicit about such things.

> Does the X state damage the circuit or half the supply voltage or both?

With A=1, the output stage cross-conducts ("X" is two lines crossed), meaning both the P and N devices are turned on. This can be destructive - or not - depending on the sizing of the devices on the semiconductor die, and the unit channel conductivity - a parameter specific to a given process.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f1j3Te.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

If you put this circuit together with discrete mosfets, they usually have high enough conductance that the output stage would burn out as it would be shorting VCC to GND through a resistance of a couple of ohms at most - and that's using mosfets from the 70s. Modern low power discrete mosfets would look like a fraction of an ohm between vcc and gnd.

> Does the X state damage the circuit or half the supply voltage or both?

If you'd use a low conductance CMOS process, like something from the mid-70s - say the 4000 logic family - the output stage would survive this. The devices in that process act like current sources that can drive a couple mA each. So, if you assembled this circuit using the transistors from a 4007 chip, it would get warm, and the output would be 1/2 VCC. If you want to actually try it, stick to low supply voltages. The 4000 family works from 3V up to 15V (and more), so at 3V this would be safe to do. At 15V, I'm not sure - it'd depend on luck, since the 4000 CMOS process has rather loose specifications.

The problem then is that connecting this 1/2 VCC voltage to an *input* would cause the input stage buffer to cross-conduct as well. So, if this were to happen in a circuit, there would be possibly several cross-conducting stages, dissipating quite a bit of heat.

> what [is] high impedance

It means that neither a P nor an N device is driving the output. The output is "floating", not really firmly connected to either VCC or GND.

High impedance state is used when multiple devices can drive the same output - typical for a bus in microprocessors, for example. A designer would ensure that exactly one device drives the bus at any time, so that the outputs connected to a bus line have "Z" states with exception of just one output that should have a "1" or "0" state.

---

If you'd want to try out a simulation, here's a circuit that can be investigated. CircuitLab does dynamic DC simulation, so currents and voltages are available in real time for all the nodes/devices - just mouse over them.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2ffGD17.png)</sup>

Answer (score 3):

As you say, I'd assume you need to generate the truth table, by considering the transistor states in sequence.

Normally the top wire is a supply, but let's come back to that...

By my reading, the left two transistors are a standard inverter.

So with A low, the middle wire is high, and vice-versa.

Looking at the right hand pair, with A(L), then the middle wire is H.  This means the top PFET is off, and so is the bottom NFET (driven directly by A).  So A(L) gives a floating output.

With A(H), the middle wire is low.  This means the top PFET is on, as is the directly driven bottom NFET.

If the top wire is a supply, the result is the supply is shorted to ground.  This is likely to let out the magic smoke...

So what the top wire is, seems unclear.  It could just be a bad example.

Comment: so I should consider the upper wire high because if it was low all the outputs would be low in all cases ,right?

Comment: Looking at the online copy of the international edition of the book, I can see this is Q3.9.  Q3.7 in the same book, is a circuit which can short the supply with a particular combination of A & B input, so I wonder whether that observation is the answer to this question.  I also note that Ed2 of the same book has an entirely different question, so it could be this question if just flawed.

Comment: a floating output means that the output is disconnected from both ground and the power supply. right? because that is a new term for me. So, I can understand that this circuit has no useful purpose, when A=0 the OUT wire is floating and when A=1 the OUT is connected to both ground and power supply which is unacceptable

Comment: @oabdullae Tri-state is a useful mechanism. Most microcontrollers have this functionality on their output pins. The ability to switch between High ouput, low output, or high-impedance allows many input/output pins to be connected together without necessarily shorting each other out.
See here for some examples of usage:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-state_logic